# AuthenticationContext.createAsync vs AuthenticationContext constructor in UWP JS app

Tags: adal

My Universal Windows Application written in JS/TypeScript uses (through .winmd) an old V2 version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory. While trying to migrate to the latest V2 ([Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 2.29.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.29.0)) version I encountered an obstacle due to a (breaking?) change in the latest versions (I tried 2.28 with the same result) - an absence of any constructors for the class `AuthenticationContext`. Instead of the constructor I am seeing a static method `createAsync` with few overloads which look like a logical equivalent of those former constructors.
Now I am forced to use the async pattern ([promises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/promise-object-javascript)) to create an instance of `AuthenticationContext` which doesn't fit my application design where I first created an instance of the context just once, stored it in a class variable and then called the context's method `acquireTokenAsync` and a property `tokenCache` to read/clear cache **at later time** which seems like not easy to achieve with the async pattern seen in the latest V2 versions.

Questions:

1. What was the reason to remove the constructor?
2. Is there a nice way to create an instance of `AuthenticationContext` and then call it later from within other, comparing to the one which created the instance,
   functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that a right way to deal with AAD in JS UWP apps is through [Web Account Manager](http://Web%20account%20manager)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to handle the asynchronous patter for the UWP via JavaScript is using the **promise** object, **then** function( refer [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps)).

There is no good way to handle this scenario, since JavaScript is executing on the single thread.